# Diffeological spaces and Sikorski differential spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Diffeological spaces and Sikorski differential spaces are each a generalisation of a smooth manifold. In their definitions, both have locality and smooth compatibility conditions. Any diffeological space is equipped with a natural topology with respect to all of its plots such that the plots are continuous, whilst any Sikorski differential space  is  equipped with the topology induced on a set by the family of functions, that is the weakest topology such that all functions from the family  are continuous. My question is what are the similarities and differences of the two spaces.

Comment: http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/25/4/25-04abs.html _We compare various different definitions of "the category of smooth objects". The definitions compared are due to Chen, Frolicher, Sikorski, Smith, and Souriau. The method of comparison is to construct functors between the categories that enable us to see how the categories relate to each other._

Comment: Thanks so much David

Comment: See also "J. Watts; Diffeologies, differential spaces, and symplectic geometry" available at arXiv:1208.3634 for a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Diffeological spaces are certain kinds of  sheaves of sets on the site of open subsets of various Euclidean (a.k.a. Cartesian) spaces.

Differential spaces are certain kinds of local $C^\infty$-ringed spaces (the sections of their structure sheaves are real-valued functions).